# Creating multiple class instances(same class) by importing data from multiple txt files

Tags: matlab

I hope I'm excused if this has been answered somewhere. I don't know all the programming terms and my searches didn't get me anything I could use.

My problem:
I have multiple txt files containing data I want to use. The names are like:

spectrum_day"number".txt

I want to make something like:

day"number" = classname(spectrum_day"number".txt)

without doing it manually for each and every file. I tried this in sheer hope that it would work.

```
f = dir('spectrum_day*.txt');
for i = 1:numel(f)
    f(i).name(1,10:length(f(i).name)-4 = day(f(i).name));
end
```

Also, I was wondering if I could access the properties of the instance by having an array of all the instance names and using something like:
"a(1).wavelength"? Or if there is another way to grab the properties from multiple instances of the same class in a loop or meaybe something else, feel free to fill me in.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but perhaps the following might get you on the right track

First to extract the day number from the file name you could use the function *regexp*. This function uses regular expression to search an input string (in your case the file name) for specific patterns. to search for a number you can use *'\d+'*. The  *\d* says look for digits (0-9) and the *+* says look for one or more in a sequence.  Putting this together you could have in your *for-loop* the following:

```
dayNumberString = regexp(f(i).name,'\d+','match'); %# Extract the digits of the day number into
                                                   %# a character array
dayNumber = str2num(dayNumberString);  %# Convert the character array to numeric data.
```

Next you need a way of loading the data from each file (I assume the function *day* from the code snippet in the question does this and returns the data as a matlab variable or class).  Then you could simply have

```
storedData(dayNumber).name = f(i).name; %#saves the file name.
storedData(dayNumber).data = day(f(i).name) %# read the file and save the result
```

Once your data is loaded you can access the data in the structure *storeData* via the index. For example, to access data for day 10 you would type *storedData(10).data*.

HTH...

Comment: @Aleksander - if Azim's answer worked for you, please hit the checkmark next to it to formally accept the answer! :)